# I am getting the image url in alert box . I need to use that url in <img src=""> in php

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp-3.0

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvuXB.png how to use that alert box url in php

Comment: _please give me solution_ really not like SO works.

Comment: Where is your code? This is just the message you get, but how you get it?

Comment: Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then try to update your question accordingly please.

Comment: And this "please give me solution" is not a good thing to say here. People are here to help, but you must help yourself by giving all information needed for this to happen.

Comment: <span style="background-color: white;border-top-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);border-right-color: white;border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);border-left-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);margin-right: -2%;" id="similar1" class="main_noti_hh_shot_h hide_per_user_xv noti_right_side_test_p noti_right_side_test1<?if(empty($store_list)){?>noti_right_side_test_no_resu<?}else{?>noti_right_side_test_bb_b noti_right_side_test_bb_bb<?}?>"> <input type="hidden" value="1" id="input_con_xrv_xrv_hh">
</span>

Comment: var myVar = document.querySelectorAll('.all_simi_pro_scroll_main_pg img')[0].src;
alert(myVar);

Comment: Edit your question, please. Comments are not a good place to post code.

Comment: Come on! I am trying to avoid to downvote you, but you are not helping. This is why you already got 3 downvotes. Don't be lazy and edit your question correctly.

Comment: Now the question is fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get img src value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765121/how-to-get-img-src-value)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of displaying alert messages through PHP using PHP alone, you must use JavaScript, you may do so in the following way:

```
   echo '<script language="javascript">;
            alert("https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvuXB.png");
         </script>';
```

You can use echo to also add HTML or in-line CSS code too.