# how to get the size of image that bind dynamically

Tags: asp.net, linq, image-size

I have Image likes ,

```
    <img runat="server" id="MyImage"/>
```

And I load the source of image at the start of page ,

```
ClsDB db = new ClsDB();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var obj = db.Context.Images.Where(x => x.id ==    
        Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"])).SingleOrDefault();
        MyImage.Src = obj.ImagePath;
    }
}
```

I want to get the original size (by `px`) of the image . How can I get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Save them to the database along with the URL, select and return to your page.  Alternatively you can use the techniques from this question to get the dimensions via JavaScript.

[JavaScript: Get image dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633264/javascript-get-image-dimensions)