# Get SVG Image Dimensions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

As stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image), the `width` and `height` attributes are required for an SVG `<image>`.

Now, I just have an image URL. I do not know the graphics size. I would instead like to retrieve it with JavaScript.

As described in an [HTML-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633264/javascript-get-image-dimensions), I can create an `Image` object and read the dimensions from there. However, this seems wasteful as (I presume) it loads the image from the specified URL just to get the size, in order to load it again in the SVG `<image>` element.

**Is there a way to retrieve the PNG graphic size directly via the SVG `<image>` element, so I can assign it to the same element's `width` and `height` properties?**

Comment: It is not wasteful. The browser will cache the image. It won't normally be loaded twice.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: Well, that's obviously what happens "physically". I would have expected the call to appear twice in the network view (even though once answered by the cache), but apparently, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Han, I was sure there were better dupe targets than this one, but can't find it right now. Anyway, yes, create an Image, that's gonna be the easiest.

Comment: @Kaiido: Thanks for the duplicate link; as so often, it was a matter of using the right search terms.

Comment: Yes, and once again this one is hard for search engines, `svg + image +` *whatever* returns a load of false positives when you want things about <image>...

Comment: You don't necessarily have to create an SVG `<image>` element. It's probably simpler to create an HTML `<img>` instead.`var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){
       alert('width: ' + image.naturalWidth + ' and height: ' + image.naturalHeight);
    };
    image.src = myImageUrl;`

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: And how do I integrate that HTML ´<img>` element in my SVG document?

Comment: You don't actually have to have an actual `<img>` element in your document. You create one in JS using `new Image()`. As per my code snippet.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Comment: Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/phfsuc9z/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: Ah, well, then that's the solution I was referring to in the question by "create an Image object and read the dimensions from there".