# 4 images in a row, how do I center specific text under each image?

Tags: html, css, image, text, center

I don't really know anything about CSS.  This question ( [How can I align text directly beneath an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225130/how-can-i-align-text-directly-beneath-an-image) ) is pretty much exactly what I need.  I have 4 images and I would like them side by side, with text that correspondences with each specific image under that image.  I've never used CSS so I got the images set in HTML up until that part using the directions in the question link that i posted, and the text for each image is under neither that image, but the images are not aligned in a row straight across, which is what I don't understand how to do.

Here is the coding I have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-with-text">
        <img src="images/CarlCall.png" border="0" alt="Carl Call"   width="177" height="229" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
        <p>Carl Call<br />(931)268-2040<br /><a href="mailto:carlcall@centergrovecoc.com">Email Carl Call</a>  </p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-with-text">
        <img src="images/sg.png" border="0" alt="Sjon Gentry" width="177" height="229" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
        <p>Sjon Gentry<br />(931)268-3273<br /><a href="mailto:sjongentry@centergrovecoc.com">Email Sjon Gentry</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-with-text">
        <img src="images/jm.png" border="0" alt="John Mabery" width="177" height="229" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
        <p>John Mabery<br />(931)268-0651<br /><a href="mailto:johnmabery@centergrovecoc.com">Email John Mabery</a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-with-text">
        <img src="images/tr.png" border="0" alt="Ted Ragland" width="177" height="229" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
        <p>Ted Ragland<br />(931)268-9387</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p> </p>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  This website for our church has just kind of got thrown at me to do, but I haven't learned CSS yet so I'm lost on some things.

Answer (score 1):

Try - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EuaMk/)

```
.img-with-text {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Where do I place the .img-with-text
part?  Like I said, I know nothing about CSS.  With most things, though, if someone points me to it, then I have no trouble doing it on my own every other time after that.  I know where the CSS files are located in joomla on the back end of our site, but I don't know which one to edit, etc.  I'm just afraid I'll mess it up.

Comment: @KristinaHammock if there is an `.img-with-text` class in your markup that almost surely means there is an associated css rule somewhere in your css files. Just look for it and edit what's there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .img-with-text { float: left; text-align: center}
    </style>

<!-- Your code -->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="img-with-text"><img src="images/CarlCall.png" border="0" alt="Carl Call"   width="177" height="229" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
    <p>Carl Call<br />(931)268-2040<br /><a href="mailto:carlcall@centergrovecoc.com">Email Carl Call</a>  </p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-with-text"><img src="images/sg.png" border="0" alt="Sjon Gentry" width="177" height="229" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
    <p>Sjon Gentry<br />(931)268-3273<br /><a href="mailto:sjongentry@centergrovecoc.com">Email Sjon Gentry</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-with-text"><img src="images/jm.png" border="0" alt="John Mabery" width="177" height="229" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
    <p>John Mabery<br />(931)268-0651<br /><a href="mailto:johnmabery@centergrovecoc.com">Email John Mabery</a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-with-text"><img src="images/tr.png" border="0" alt="Ted Ragland" width="177" height="229" style="border: 2px solid black;" />
    <p>Ted Ragland<br />(931)268-9387</p>
    </div>
    </div>

<!-- End of your code -->
    <p style="clear: both">Something more here </p>
```

Comment: Where do I put the style type=
part at?  Like I said, I have no understanding of CSS.  :(

Comment: The easiest for you is to place it inside head tag (section) of your HTML document http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/a/where-to-put-css.htm for more information. But if you want to re-use it on other (sub)website that you may want to put it externally.

Comment: Maybe I should add that Head tag will be very close to the beginning of the HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `text-align: center` in your css for class `.img-with-text`, and maybe display images as block. Something like this:

```
.img-with-text { float: left; text-align: center; }
.img-with-text img { display: block; }
```