# Pictures Css diagram

Tags: html, css

I want to put the horizontal pictures along line and the names below

```
<div class="imgages">
<img src="rock.png"/><p>Rock</p>
<img src="paper.png"/><p>Paper</p>
<img src="scissors.png" /><p>Scissors</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to need to use some different containers. Try <div><img /><span>title</span></div> as a layout. You can then put the divs in a container and float the inner divs so they sit next to each other

Comment: Use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225130/how-can-i-align-text-directly-beneath-an-image as a start...

Comment: Use the CSS property `float:left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **TRY** - **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j61ugft6/6/)** [EDITED]

For horizontal align pictures use `display: inline-block;`:

**TRY**

```
div.images img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Use HTML5 `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` Tags for get the names below:

**Example:**

```
<!-- Figure with figcaption -->
<figure>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYeVn.png" alt="An awesome picture">    
    <figcaption><b>NAME:</b> Caption for the awesome picture</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**Result:**

[image: An awesome picture]
    **NAME:** Caption for the awesome picture

For more info:

> **Mozilla MDN** - [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

**FOR BOTH:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="images">
<figure>
    <img src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png" alt="An awesome picture">    
    <figcaption><b>NAME:</b> Caption picture</figcaption>
</figure>
    <figure>
    <img src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png" alt="An awesome picture">    
    <figcaption><b>NAME:</b> Caption picture</figcaption>
</figure>
        <figure>
    <img src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png" alt="An awesome picture">    
    <figcaption><b>NAME:</b> Caption picture</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.images figure {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @user3478941 I'm glad I was able to help and don't forget to - [TRY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j61ugft6/1/) :)

Comment: This is a well explained answer. However you should not be using floats for basic layout in 2014. Just make the image `display: block`.

Comment: I’m additionally a little disappointed that you didn’t correct OP’s spelling. imgages? Seriously?

Answer (score 0):

Technique without the use of `float`.
Use `display:inline-block` to align the innner`div`s containing the image in a single line and add the image and text into the inner `div`s.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0jnLnq64/)**