# CSS: Show Text centered under List points

Tags: html, css

i want to make a menu with an unorderd list.

I already changed the itempoints to an image.

What i want is that the text is centered under the itempoints.

I already made the list horizontally by using float:left.

```
<ul style="list-syle: none;">   
    <li style="list-style-image: url(layout/img/content/pb_beruf.png); float:left; text-align:center;">Beruf</li>
    <li style="list-style-image: url(layout/img/content/pb_sprache.png); float:left; text-align:center;">Sprache</li>
    <li style="list-style-image: url(layout/img/content/pb_gesundheit.png); float:left; text-align:center;">Gesundheit</li>
    <li style="list-style-image: url(layout/img/content/pb_kultur.png); float:left; text-align:center;">Kultur</li>
    <li style="list-style-image: url(layout/img/content/pb_gesellschaft.png); float:left; text-align:center;">Gesellschaft</li>
    <li style="list-style-image: url(layout/img/content/pb_grundbildung.png); float:left; text-align:center;">Grundbildung</li> 
</ul>
```

But how can i move the text under the itempoints and center it?

€:

point    point point point

text  text text text

the text should be centered to the point above

€2:
Thanks for everyones help. I can't upvote you because of not enough reputations.

Solution:

```
<ul style="list-syle: none;">   
            <li style="list-style:none; background: url(layout/img/content/pb_beruf.png) center top no-repeat; float:left; text-align:center; padding-top:70px;  width: 100px;">Beruf</li>
            <li style="list-style:none; background: url(layout/img/content/pb_sprache.png) center top no-repeat; float:left; text-align:center; padding-top:70px;  width: 100px;">Sprache</li>
            <li style="list-style:none; background: url(layout/img/content/pb_gesundheit.png) center top no-repeat; float:left; text-align:center; padding-top:70px; width: 100px;">Gesundheit</li>
            <li style="list-style:none; background: url(layout/img/content/pb_kultur.png) center top no-repeat; float:left; text-align:center; padding-top:70px; width: 100px;">Kultur</li>
            <li style="list-style:none; background: url(layout/img/content/pb_gesellschaft.png) center top no-repeat; float:left; text-align:center; padding-top:70px; width: 100px;">Gesellschaft</li>
            <li style="list-style:none; background: url(layout/img/content/pb_grundbildung.png) center top no-repeat; float:left; text-align:center; padding-top:70px; width: 100px;">Grundbildung</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Center and under doesn't quite say much? If it's hard to explain...Can you put it in a fiddler?

Comment: You have a typo: `list-syle: none`. You can't center the text because the text is going to take up 100% of the container width anyway. Use a `background-image` instead and set it's center position to 50%. Or set a fixed width on the elements

Comment: you means to say image and text should be align vertically? If yes then follow above comment posted by @RGraham

Comment: i want to look it like my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/0c5ejr82/1/
 try using background image
,example code:

```
li{list-style:none; 
background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_ie.gif) center top no-repeat; 
float:left; 
text-align:center; 
padding-top:20px;}
```

Comment: At First thanks for your help. That seems to work for me. The only problem here is that the images are overlapping

Comment: Try to adjust it with padding-top. If they are overlapping in width, try to set width of li element. Your code would look better if you use classes instead of inline css - > http://jsfiddle.net/0c5ejr82/5/

Comment: i used width now. And it works fine thanks for your help. i clean up the code now. Im inside of an cms so its easier to use inline in the development. Or i have to change the window every time

Comment: @Ingrimmsch you can further show your appreciation by marking this as an answer

Comment: thx for the info i marked it

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `::before` (or `::after`) CSS pseudo-elements in place of the list-markers you're currently using:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block; /* or 'float: left' if you prefer */
  position: relative; /* to allow the pseudo-elements to be placed in
                         relation to this element */
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 17px; /* to provide 'room' for the pseudo-elements */
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

li::before {
  content: url("http://placehold.it/30x30"); /* the image to show */
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px; /* centring the images against the top border */
  border-radius: 50%; /* aesthetic, adjust, or remove, to taste */
  overflow: hidden; /* again: aesthetic, adjust, or remove, to taste */
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-syle: none;">
  <li>Beruf</li>
  <li>Sprache</li>
  <li>Gesundheit</li>
  <li>Kultur</li>
  <li>Gesellschaft</li>
  <li>Grundbildung</li>
</ul>
```

Given the images you're using, though, you'll need to specify the content of each pseudo-element specifically:

```
li:nth-child(1)::before {
    content: url(layout/img/content/pb_beruf.png);
}
li:nth-child(2)::before {
    content: url(layout/img/content/pb_sprache.png)
}
/* ...etc... */
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing this demo will help u.

```
<div id="menu-outer">
<div class="table">
<ul id="horizontal-list">
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list-item-1.gif" alt="list item 1" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list-item-2.gif" alt="list item 2" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list-item-3.gif" alt="list item 3" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/list-item-4.gif" alt="list item 4" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
#menu-outer {
height: 84px;
background: url(images/bar-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}

.table {
display: table;   /* Allow the centering to work */
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#horizontal-list {
min-width: 696px;
list-style: none;
padding-top: 20px;
}
ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have adopted the solution from this question and modified to yours.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225130/how-can-i-align-text-directly-beneath-an-image
```

**Few tips from side AFAIK**
1.Never use inline styling..as it will override any styling done on that element.
2. Use classes and always keep your code clean by putting CSS seperately.

```
<ul>
<li>
 <div class="class1">
    <img src="layout/img/content/pb_beruf.png" />
    <p>Beruf</p>
 </div>
 </li>
<li>    
<div class="class1">
    <img src="layout/img/content/pb_sprache.png" />
    <p>Sprache</p>
</div>
 </li>  

   .... 

</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
  float:left;
}

.class1 {
    text-align: justify;
    width:100px;
}

.class1 img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you just adjust your width of image , i think it should work. I havent checked it but i guess it should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Normally i use a seperated CSS. But im in the context of a cms and for testing i use inline styling and seperate it after it works. I can't do it this way because the list points must be images :/